# Why android application gives compiler error for Admob integration using Firebase using c++ SDK

Tags: android, c++, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

I want to integrate AdMob in cocos2dx 3.17 c++. I have referred https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/cocos2d-x link. But I am getting error :

```
Error while executing process /Users/Test/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/Projets/AmazingWordQuest/proj.android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target MyGame}
[1/718] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp.o 
/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DANDROID -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DLWS_WITH_LIBUV -DMyGame_EXPORTS -DUSE_FILE32API -I../../../../../../Classes -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/audio/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos -I../../../../../../cocos2d/extensions -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/base -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/Box2D/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/chipmunk/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/freetype2/include/android/freetype2 -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/recast/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/jpeg/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/uv/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/webp/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include/bullet -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/openssl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tiff/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/websockets/include/android -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tinyxml2/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxhash/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxtea/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/clipper/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/edtaa3func/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/ConvertUTF/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/poly2tri/.. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/md5/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/curl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/png/include/android -I/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/sources/android/cpufeatures -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/src -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/tremolo/. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/zlib/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/unzip/. -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp.o -c ../../../../../../Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp
In file included from ../../../../../../Classes/FirebaseHelper.cpp:1:
../../../../../../Classes/FirebaseHelper.h:7:10: fatal error: 'firebase/admob/types.h' file not found
#include "firebase/admob/types.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[2/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionManager.cpp.o
[3/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionInstant.cpp.o
[4/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionProgressTimer.cpp.o
[5/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionPageTurn3D.cpp.o
[6/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionGrid.cpp.o
[7/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionTiledGrid.cpp.o
[8/718] Building CXX object engine/cocos/core/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/2d/CCActionInterval.cpp.o
[9/718] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o 
/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DANDROID -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DLWS_WITH_LIBUV -DMyGame_EXPORTS -DUSE_FILE32API -I../../../../../../Classes -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/audio/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos -I../../../../../../cocos2d/extensions -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/base -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/Box2D/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/chipmunk/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/freetype2/include/android/freetype2 -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/recast/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/jpeg/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/uv/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/webp/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include/bullet -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/openssl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tiff/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/websockets/include/android -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tinyxml2/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxhash/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxtea/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/clipper/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/edtaa3func/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/ConvertUTF/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/poly2tri/.. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/md5/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/curl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/png/include/android -I/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/sources/android/cpufeatures -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/src -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/tremolo/. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/zlib/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/unzip/. -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o -c ../../../../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp
../../../../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:28:10: fatal error: 'firebase/app.h' file not found
#include "firebase/app.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[10/718] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o 
/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DANDROID -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DLWS_WITH_LIBUV -DMyGame_EXPORTS -DUSE_FILE32API -I../../../../../../Classes -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/audio/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos -I../../../../../../cocos2d/extensions -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/base -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support -I../../../../../../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/Box2D/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/chipmunk/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/freetype2/include/android/freetype2 -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/recast/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/jpeg/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/uv/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/webp/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/bullet/include/bullet -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/openssl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tiff/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/websockets/include/android -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/tinyxml2/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxhash/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/xxtea/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/clipper/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/edtaa3func/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/ConvertUTF/. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/poly2tri/.. -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/md5/.. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/curl/include/android -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/png/include/android -I/Users/Test/Work/Live/Cocos2d/SDK_Framework/android-ndk-r19b/sources/android/cpufeatures -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/pvmp3dec/src -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/android-specific/tremolo/. -isystem ../../../../../../cocos2d/external/zlib/include -I../../../../../../cocos2d/external/unzip/. -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o -c ../../../../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
In file included from ../../../../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:28:
../../../../../../Classes/FirebaseHelper.h:7:10: fatal error: 'firebase/admob/types.h' file not found
#include "firebase/admob/types.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja:build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the h files. make sure to update your LOCAL_C_INCLUDES with the correct path